# Is this a memory leak in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, memory-leaks

```
// CMyDialog inherits from CDialog 
void CMyFrame::OnBnClickedCreate()
{
    CMyDialog* dlg = new CMyDialog();
    dlg->Create( IDD_MYDIALOG, m_thisFrame );
    dlg->ShowWindow( SW_SHOW );
}
```

I'm pretty sure this leaks.  What I'm really asking is: is there any "magic" in MFC that does dialog cleanup when the dialog is destroyed.  How would it work if dlg wasn't a pointer but declared on the stack - wouldn't the destructor destroy the window when dlg goes out of scope.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it is memory leak in your case but you can avoid memory leak in cases where modeless dialog allocated on the heap by making use of overriding `PostNcDestroy`.

Dialogs are not designed for auto-cleanup ( where as Main frame windows, View windows are).
In case you want to provide the auto-cleanup for dialogs then you must override the `PostNcDestroy` member function in your derived class. To add auto-cleanup to your class, call your base class and then do a `delete this`. To remove auto-cleanup from your class, call `CWnd::PostNcDestroy` directly instead of the `PostNcDestroy` member in your direct base class.

```
void MyDialog::PostNcDestroy() 
{

    CDialog::PostNcDestroy();
    delete this;
}
```

How this works (from MSDN):

> When destroying a Windows window, the
>   last Windows message sent to the
>   window is WM_NCDESTROY. The default
>   CWnd handler for that message
>   (CWnd::OnNcDestroy) will detach the
>   HWND from the C++ object and call the
>   virtual function PostNcDestroy. Some
>   classes override this function to
>   delete the C++ object.
>
> "delete this" will free any C++
>   memory associated with the C++ object.
>   Even though the default CWnd
>   destructor calls DestroyWindow if
>   m_hWnd is non-NULL, this does not lead
>   to infinite recursion since the handle
>   will be detached and NULL during the
>   cleanup phase.

You can also refer MSDN ([Destroying Window Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zba4hah.aspx) ) for further details.

**Note:**

This works for modeless dialog that can be allocated on the **heap**.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's a leak. And yes, the window would be destroyed if the object was stack-allocated. Using dialogs as stack-allocated objects is typical for modal dialogs - you call a method for showing a dialog as a modal window and that method only returns when the dialog is closed and the object is destroyed after that.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say this is for a Modeless dialog. I'm assuming in this case for cleanup the dialog object has to be a member variable - so it can be destroyed/de-allocated in the frames destructor.

Answer (score 3):

If you manually call **`Create`** on a dialog, you have to manually **`Destroy`** it as well.
When using **`DoModal()`** this isn't necessary.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd(VS.80).aspx):

> Use the CWnd::DestroyWindow function
>   to destroy a dialog box created by the
>   Create function.