# MFC: Deleting dynamically created CWnd objects

Tags: c++, mfc

Lets say in a dialog, we dynamically create a variable number of CWnds... like creating a and registering a CButton every time the user does something/

Some pseudo-code...

```
class CMyDlg : public CDialog
{
 vector<CWnd *> windows;

 void onClick()
 {
  CButton *pButton = new CButton(...);
  //do other stuff like position it here
  windows.push_back(pButton);
 }
}
```

Do I *need* to explicitly delete them or will MFC do it? If I have to, would it be in the destructor as normal, or are there any special things to avoid breaking MFC... making sure I don't delete the objects while the HWNDs are still in use for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CButton *pButton = new CButton(...);
```

These are C++ objects, which needs to be deleted explicitly.  (Where as Main frame windows and Views are self destructed).

You can refer the detailed answer ( by me) [Destroying Window Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944033/is-this-a-memory-leak-in-mfc/944190#944190)

Comment: but how main frame is self destructed? you have this `delete pFrame;` in `App::ExitInstance()` .