# How to free CWin objects created in a child diaolog to avoid memory leaks

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm creating a a CStatic conrol in a child dialog, which works fine. The problem is that after closing the child dialog the memory is not freed correctly.

I tried to overwrite `PostNCDestoy` like described in the this thread:
[Is this a memory leak in MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944033/is-this-a-memory-leak-in-mfc)
But this gives me an unhandled exception by calling "delete this".

Any idea what the right way is to release CStatic, CButtons to avoid memory leaks?

**CChildDlg.h**

```
class CChildDlg
{
  std::vector<CStatic*> m_images;
  void addNewImage(const int &xPos, const int &yPos)
  ...
}
```

**CChildDlg.cpp**

```
void CChildDlg::addNewImage(const int &xPos, const int &yPos){

  CImage imgFromFile;
  CStatic *img = new CStatic;

  imgFromFile.Load(_T("someImg.jpg"));
  int width = imgFromFile.GetWidth();
  int height = imgFromFile.GetHeight();


  img->Create(_T("Image"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP,
    CRect(xPos, yPos, xPos + width, yPos + height), this, 10910);

  HBITMAP hbmOld = img->SetBitmap(imgFromFile.Detach());
  if (hbmOld != nullptr){
    ::DeleteObject(hbmOld);
  }
  m_images.pushback(img);
}
```

Based on the recommendations in this thread I changed the code like followed:

**CChildDlg.h**

```
class CChildDlg
{
private:
  typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr <CStatic>> CStaticImgs;
  CStaticImgs m_images;
  void addNewImage(const int &xPos, const int &yPos)
  ...
}
```

**CChildDlg.cpp**

```
void CChildDlg::addNewImage(const int &xPos, const int &yPos){

  CImage imgFromFile;
  std::unique_ptr<CStatic> img(new CStatic);

  imgFromFile.Load(_T("someImg.jpg"));
  int width = imgFromFile.GetWidth();
  int height = imgFromFile.GetHeight();

  img->Create(_T("Image"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP,
     CRect(xPos, yPos, xPos + width, yPos + height), this, 10910);

  HBITMAP hbmOld = img->SetBitmap(imgFromFile.Detach());
  if (hbmOld != nullptr){
     ::DeleteObject(hbmOld);
  }
  m_images.pushback(std::move(img));
}
```

The code works fine, but the leak is still there. Only if I'm removing the line where I'm setting the Bitmap to the CStatic the leak disappears:

```
//HBITMAP hbmOld = img->SetBitmap(imgFromFile.Detach());
//if (hbmOld != nullptr){
  //::DeleteObject(hbmOld);
//}
```

So, it has to be related to taking over the ownership of the CImage to the CStatic somehow. I'm loading up to 100 images to the dialog. By every opening of the dialog I still can see a significant raise of the memory, which not drops after closing it.

Any other suggestion what might be wrong of missing?

Comment: Don't create CStatic dynamically, put it into CChildDlg as a member.

Comment: My number of CStatic objects is only known at runtime.

Comment: Are you really sure that you have a memory leak? Did you debug and set and not hit a breakpoint in the destructor of your child window (add any custom window to your window to test this)? The answer you reference is about modeless dialog windows, not child windows of main frames (which the poster specifically excluded from his answer.)

Comment: Your container class should be storing the objects themselves, not pointers to them. Then, when the container goes out of scope (i.e., when the class's destructor is called), it will automatically free all of the `CStatic` objects that it contains.

Comment: Where is your code to delete the CStatic in m_images? The vector's dtor will not delete the CStatics automatically.

Comment: What exactly is reported as being leaked?

Comment: @CodyGray this is what I tried a first. Unfortunately CObject are not copyable.

Comment: @WernerHenze, that's a good point. I thought the vector dtor will do so. I will dig in the code later this day.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Although copyable isn't technically a requirement for the standard containers, I suppose these MFC classes are not moveable either. Use smart pointers, then. Make a vector of `std::unique_ptr` objects, which will automatically delete the CStatic objects through the pointer once the vector goes out of scope. (The fundamental point is, make use of [SBRM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) and modern C++ idioms, rather than manually calling delete.)

Comment: @CodyGray You should add that as an answer :).

Comment: @WernerHenze I checked the number of GDI objects using processexplorer. I can see a significant raise of the objects by the amount of loaded images, but no decrease after closing the dialog. Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 3):

The naïve solution would be to simply iterate through your container class, calling `delete` on each pointer. Something like:

```
for (auto i : m_images)                       { delete i; }            // on C++11
```

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < m_images.size(); ++i)  { delete m_images[i]; }  // on C++03
```

If you do this in your destructor or in response to the `WM_DESTROY` message (`OnDestroy` in MFC), it will ensure that each of your `CStatic` instances are destroyed, solving the memory leak problem.

But this is not the best solution. In C++, you should be taking advantage of [Scope-Bound Resource Management (SBRM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii), also more commonly known as RAII. This involves the use of language features to *automatically* clean up objects, rather than having to do it manually. Not only does this make the code cleaner, but it ensures that you never forget, that your code is fully exception-safe, and may even be more efficient.

Typically, you would just store the objects themselves in the container class. That is, instead of `std::vector<CStatic*>`, you would just have `std::vector<CStatic>`. That way, whenever the vector container is destroyed (which happens automatically when it goes out of scope, thanks to SBRM), all of the objects that it contains get destroyed as well (*i.e.*, their destructors are called automatically).

However, the standard-library containers require that objects be either copyable or movable. The MFC classes derived from `CObject` are not copyable, and presumably not movable either (given the age of MFC and the standard idioms for making an object non-copyable implicitly making it non-movable). That means this won't work: you can't store `CStatic` objects themselves in a vector or other container class.

Fortunately, modern C++ has a solution for this problem: the [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one). Smart pointers are just what they sound like: a class that wraps the bare ("dumb") pointer, giving it superpowers. Chief among the smarts offered by a smart pointer is SBRM. Whenever the smart pointer object gets destroyed, it automatically deletes its underlying dumb pointer. This frees you, the humble programmer, from ever having to write a single `delete` statement. In fact, two things you should almost never have to do in C++ are:

- explicitly write `delete`
- use raw pointers

So my recommendation, given the limitations of MFC's `CObject`-derived classes, is to store smart pointers in your vector. The syntax isn't pretty, but that's trivially solved with a typedef:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CStatic>> CStaticVector;   // for C++11
```

(For C++03, since [`std::auto_ptr` cannot be used in a standard container](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/025.htm) [again, because it is not copyable], you would need to use a different smart pointer, such as the [Boost Smart Pointers library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).)

No more manual memory-management, no more memory leaks, no more headaches. Working in C++ literally goes from being a pain in the butt to being fast, fun, and efficient.

Comment: std::vector of std::auto_ptr is prohibited combination.

Comment: @Anatoly Ugh, I always forget about how dumb auto_ptr is. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @CodyGray thank you very much for your vary detailed answer. I changed my code, where I'm using smart pointers now. One note on this: std::unique_ptr is also not copyable just moveable, quite rightly! For details see the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283778/why-can-i-not-push-back-a-unique-ptr-into-a-vector. However, using smart pointers didn't solve my problem. I will update my post with my new insights.

Answer (score 0):

In `CChildDlg` destructor add `for(auto img : m_images) delete img;`.

Answer (score 0):

What I realised is that only by taking care of a proper clean up of the `HBITMAP`s which are returned while calling `.Detach()` the number of GDI objects is decreasing to a correct value and the memory leak disappears.

**CChildDlg.h**

```
HBITMAT m_deleteMeWhenClosingDlg;
....
```

**CChildDlg.cpp**

```
  ...
  m_deleteMeWhenClosingDlg = imgFromFile.Detach();
  HBITMAP hbmOld = img->SetBitmap(m_deleteMeWhenClosingDlg);
  ...
```

Later in OnDestroy() for example

```
  ::DeleteObject(m_deleteMeWhenClosingDlg)
```